# Excel 2013 Scale to Fit Page by Page Breaks

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

QU: Is there a way I can have 'shrink to fit page' work on blocks of rows independently?

Details: I have a spreadsheet with blocks of data for each day of the year, with about 50 rows each, and I want to print out each day on one and only one sheet of paper. However, some of the blocks are a little longer and spill over to the next page. If I turn on shrink to fit with page breaks in place, I instead get all of the blocks crammed on to on page.

Answer (score 0):

No, if I understand you correctly, it's not possible. But as a workaround, for example, you could use the automatic line break for individual cells/rows thus limiting the "spill over".